# How to change a part of a div class name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, class, replace, rename

There is a div class labeled, #Roster-1000115-Color. This div element is a drop down menu that allows you to select different colors. The 1000115 is a session token, so that number is constantly changing. I need to replace that with a number that represents the color value.

For example, if I click the drop down menu and I select 'White' I need the div class to rename to #Roster-FFFFFF-Color.

I need a javascript function that will identify that session id number, and then replace with a constant value.

I have been trying to use REGEX to search for that number. I'm not sure how to identity that session ID, and then replace it with a list of color values.

Comment: Do you have any code yet?

Comment: I find your description confusing.  Please post some example markup and code.  Consider using jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: @dtanders or consider using **Stack Overflow Snippets** - its the little document icon with the `</>` in it when you are editing your post. On a more relevant note, why use regex or anything like that at all? Just create a new classname `'Roster-' + colorstring + '-Color'` and remove the old class. Using regex for this is overkill as its slow.

Comment: @somethinghere good point - I keep forgetting they added that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this regex? https://regex101.com/r/vE3oY6/2

```
/#Roster-([0-9a-f]{6})-Color/gi
```

Here's the breakdown for the `([0-9a-f]{6})` part:

```
(                   //Start capturing group
  [0-9a-f]{6}       //Find any digit or letter from a to f recurring exactly 6 times
)
```

`gi` means checking for the regex globally (many times) and case insensitive since class or id should be case-insensitive.

Comment: Regex is a bit of a heavy solution but it does indeed work. TBH, better avoid regex if you can as its pretty slow.

Comment: @somethinghere since the question is a bit vague, i can only catch the "I've been trying regex" part. Performance won't be an issue here I dont think.